# How do I install Java 6 for use in Chrome?

Tags: java, google-chrome, versions

I'm using an application for my employee timecards update. It will only run with Java version 6. Now after switching to Google Chrome, I'm facing an issue with this application.

How do I install and use the older version of Java on Chrome without being notified by Chrome browser everytime? I had tried the steps to add flag on chrome `/icon/target`, but it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to install Java to Chrome at the moment. NPAPI plugins are not supported on linux any more. But I have not heard of any existing PPAPI Java plugins now.
I use Firefox for Java.